# Remapping Custom objects to Standard Objects

Tags: custom-object, data-loader, standard-objects, data-export, data-migration

I'm currently working with a company where we use Salesforce as a social platform; all the sales data &  purchasing information is handled separately at the moment, with certain data available via an AS400. However: at the time of its invocation into the company, the users didn't realize that Salesforce had standard objects for things like Orders & Pricebooks, nor had they realized that standard objects, like Account or Contact, could have custom fields to separate individual customers from full corporations. Would it be possible to use the Data Export tool to export the data of the custom objects and remap them to Standard objects? I'm assuming that the standard objects would have any custom fields needed to preserve all data being remapped.

Comment: Thank god. ⊂(___⊂) Thankfully, the previous users had not made too many custom object "clones", and also, the schema explorer will help view what needs to be mapped where. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just the fields that you wanna move from Custom objects to standard objects I would suggest you to do it manually since it is a declarative framework and can take a closer look at the permissions and field level security.  you can look at the Naming Conventions too.

Also if you wanna move the data from the existing custom object fields to standard object fields go with the data loader. You can export the data from custom object fields and you can upsert it to the standard object custom fields which you create using dataloader through simple csv files.

DataLoader

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader

Comment: That's what I was planning on doing! c(●▽● )

Comment: I also could use MavensMate, if I really had to